# Apresentação falhando em árvore binária

Tags: c, árvore-binária

> Não consigo apresentar minha árvore nem em ordem nem em preOrdem assim como no exemplo abaixo o cursor apenas some e espera outra instrução

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tipoNo{
    int valor;
    struct tipoNo *esq; 
    struct tipoNo *dir;

}TNo;

TNo* inserir (TNo *raiz, int valorParametro){ 

    if (raiz == NULL){
        raiz = new TNo; // criação de um novo no 
        raiz->valor = valorParametro;
        raiz->dir = NULL;
        raiz->esq = NULL;
    } else{
        if (valorParametro < raiz->valor){
            raiz->esq = inserir(raiz->esq ,valorParametro); 
        } else{
            raiz->dir = inserir(raiz->dir ,valorParametro);
        }
    }
    return raiz;
}

int consultaRecursiva (TNo *raiz ,int itemConsulta){
    if (raiz == NULL){
        printf("Sua Arvore esta vazia !! \n");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (raiz->valor == itemConsulta){
            printf("Achou !!!!");
            system("pause");
            return 1 ;
        } else{
            if (raiz->valor > itemConsulta){
                return consultaRecursiva(raiz->esq ,itemConsulta);

            } else{
                return consultaRecursiva(raiz->dir ,itemConsulta);

            }
        }
    }
}

void preOrdem (TNo *raiz_aux){
    if (raiz_aux != NULL){
        printf("%d", raiz_aux->valor);
        preOrdem(raiz_aux->esq);
        preOrdem(raiz_aux->dir);
        system("pause");
    }
}



int main (){
    TNo *raiz; // ponteiro do tipo NO
    raiz = NULL; // a raiz DEVE estar nula
    int op;

    do {
        system("cls");
        printf ("INFORME UMA OPCAO ");
        printf ("\nPara inserir digite 1 ");
        printf ("\nPara consultar digite 2 ");
        printf ("\nPara preOrdem digite 3 \n");
        printf ("Para sair digite 0 : ");
        scanf ("%d",&op);

        if (op == 1){
            int novoValor;
            printf("Entre com um novo valor : ");
            scanf ("%d",&novoValor);
            inserir (raiz ,novoValor);
        }
        if (op == 2){
            int itemPesquisa;
            printf("Entre com uma elemento para a busca : ");
            scanf ("%d",&itemPesquisa);
            consultaRecursiva(raiz ,itemPesquisa);

        }
        if (op == 3){

            preOrdem(raiz);
        }

    }while(op != 0);

}
```

Comment: Isso é C ou C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há alguns poucos probleminhas em seu código:

```
#include <conio.h>
```

Não use isso. Essa biblioteca é super antiquada, obsoleta e não é uma biblioteca padrão. Além disso, ela não está sendo usada para nada, só está no seu código de bobeira.

A sua função `consultaRecursiva` confunde a árvore vazia com a árvore que não contém o elemento procurado. A forma mais simples de resolver isso é simplesmente mudando a mensagem de erro. Uma forma melhor é separar a lógica de exibição de mensagens da lógica de consulta. Isso é possível se a função `consultaRecursiva` retornar o nó onde o elemento foi encontrado ao invés de 0 ou 1. Afinal, no mundo real, quem for fazer uma busca de um elemento em uma árvore binária vai provavelmente querer saber onde este elemento está, e não apenas se ele está lá ou não.

Na função `main`, o seu erro está aqui:

```
inserir (raiz ,novoValor);
```

O que você queria era isso:

```
raiz = inserir(raiz, novoValor);
```

Um outro detalhe é essa linha:

```
raiz = new TNo; // criação de um novo no
```

Como você aqui parece estar trabalhando com C, e não com C++ (o `new` é algo do C++), então vamos usar `malloc` no lugar disso:

```
raiz = (Tno *) malloc(sizeof Tno);
```

Esse `system("pause");` dentro da sua função `preOrdem` vai fazer o sistema ficar bem engasgado em árvores grandes, fazendo você ter que pressionar uma tecla para cada nó, o que é muito chato. Retire isso.

Além disso, dá para dar uma simplificada em alguns pontos do código (principalmente ao usar `else if`). Veja abaixo como fica:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tipoNo {
    int valor;
    struct tipoNo *esq; 
    struct tipoNo *dir;
} TNo;

TNo* inserir(TNo *no, int valorParametro) { 
    if (no == NULL) {
        no = (Tno *) malloc(sizeof Tno);
        no->valor = valorParametro;
        no->dir = NULL;
        no->esq = NULL;
    } else if (valorParametro < no->valor) {
        no->esq = inserir(no->esq, valorParametro); 
    } else {
        no->dir = inserir(no->dir, valorParametro);
    }
    return no;
}

TNo *consultaRecursiva(TNo *no, int itemConsulta) {
    if (no == NULL) return NULL;
    if (no->valor == itemConsulta) return no;
    TNo *lado = no->valor > itemConsulta ? no->esq : no->dir;
    return consultaRecursiva(lado, itemConsulta);
}

void preOrdem(TNo *no) {
    if (no != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", no->valor);
        preOrdem(no->esq);
        preOrdem(no->dir);
    }
}

int main() {
    TNo *raiz = NULL;
    int op;

    do {
        system("cls");
        printf("INFORME UMA OPCAO ");
        printf("\nPara inserir digite 1");
        printf("\nPara consultar digite 2");
        printf("\nPara preOrdem digite 3\n");
        printf("Para sair digite 0: ");
        scanf("%d", &op);

        if (op == 1) {
            int novoValor;
            printf("Entre com um novo valor: ");
            scanf("%d", &novoValor);
            raiz = inserir(raiz, novoValor);
        } else if (op == 2) {
            int itemPesquisa;
            printf("Entre com uma elemento para a busca : ");
            scanf ("%d", &itemPesquisa);
            TNo *achou = consultaRecursiva(raiz, itemPesquisa);
            if (raiz == NULL) {
                printf("Sua arvore esta vazia.\n");
            } else if (achou == NULL) {
                printf("O elemento %d nao esta na arvore.\n", itemPesquisa);
            } else {
                printf("O elemento %d esta na arvore.\n", itemPesquisa);
            }
            system("pause");
        } else if (op == 3) {
            preOrdem(raiz);
            system("pause");
        }
    } while(op != 0);
}
```

Também é sempre importante você ter uma função para limpar aquilo que é alocado dinamicamente em memória. Deixo esse para você.

Comment: Obrigado pelo apoio consegui resolver todos os problemas .É um exercício de faculdade então ajudou muito .